# Using the caret::train package for calculating prediction error (MdAE) of glmms with beta-binomial errors

Tags: r, r-caret, glm

The question is more or less as the title indicates. I would like to use the `caret::train` function with beta-binomial models made with `glmmTMB` package (although I am not opposed to other functions capable of fitting beta-binomial models) to calculate median absolute error (MdAE) estimates through jack-knife (leave-one-out) cross-validation. The `glmmTMBControl` function is already capable of estimating the optimal dispersion parameter but I was hoping to retain this information somehow as well... or having caret do the calculation possibly?

The dataset I am working with looks like this:

```
 df <- data.frame(Effect = rep(seq(from = 0.05, to = 1, by = 0.05), each = 5), Time = rep(seq(1:20), each = 5))
```

Ideally I would be able to pass the `glmmTMB` function to `trainControl` like so:

```
BB.glmm1 <- train(Time ~ Effect, 
              data = df, method = "glmmTMB", 
              method = "", metric = "MAD")
```

The output would be as per the examples contained in train, although possibly with estimates for the dispersion parameter.

Although I am in no way opposed to work arounds - Thank you in advance!

Comment: is MdAE just median of the residuals?

Comment: Yes, as I understand it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure how to perform the required operation with caret without creating a custom method but I trust it is fairly easy to implement it with a `for` (`lapply`) loop.
In the example I will use the  `sleepstudy` data set since your example data throws a bunch of warnings.

```
library(glmmTMB)
```

to perform LOOCV - for every row, create a model without that row and predict on that row:

```
data(sleepstudy,package="lme4")

LOOCV <- lapply(1:nrow(sleepstudy), function(x){
  m1 <- glmmTMB(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject),
                data = sleepstudy[-x,])
  return(predict(m1, sleepstudy[x,], type = "response"))
})
```

get the median of the residuals (I think this is MdAE? if not post a comment on how its calculated):

```
median(abs(unlist(LOOCV) - sleepstudy$Reaction))
```